# I am getting the following error when in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

Getting the following error:

> CS1061: 'regsupplier_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'registerbtn_Click1' and no extension method 'registerbtn_Click1' accepting a first argument of type 'regsupplier_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
<asp:Button ID="registerbtn" CssClass="register" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="registerbtn_Click1" />
```

Comment: We can't tell you what is wrong with your code without seeing it. Please share the click event's signature and where you are calling it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it would be good to show the code (regsupplier.aspx) but if you are confident that you can solve it without sharing the code, then please check that your regsupplier.aspx or any class therein referencing the `Click1` property or method of your `registerbtn` object has access to this object by including it in the `using` statement

Comment: Well, *does* that event handler exist?

Comment: Check your code behind and see if there's a method named `registerbtn_Click1`

Comment: Yes event handler exists

Comment: protected void registerbtn_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Successful");
        }

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, You have defined an OnClick event for your asp:Button in the asp page but you haven't defined the same in your .cs page. define them to solve the issue

```
protected void registerbtn_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // code here
}
```

**Exceptional cases:**

- If you don't this event for the button, then remove `OnClick="registerbtn_Click1"` from the markup
- If you already defined `registerbtn_Click` in the `.cs` page means rename the same in the markup as `OnClick="registerbtn_Click"`

Comment: FWIW, I already made a similar point in the comments, as did @ekad. The OP doesn't show their code, but I'm assuming that the OP simply forgot to define the method.

Comment: The event handler also exists